# How to use IntelliJ's structural replacement for "all matches, except..."?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Lets say I want to replace `print(x)` with `print(wrapper(x))`.  I can match

```
print($Argument$)
```

and replace it with

```
print(wrapper($Argument$))
```

However, if I already have a call to `print(wrapper(x))`, I don't want to replace that with `print(wrapper(wrapper(x)))`.  How can I avoid that?  In other words, how do I say "do the replacement, unless the arguments match some pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would:

1. Input search template (for example): `System.out.println($args$)`
2. Click `Edit Variables`
3. Choose the `$args$` variable
4. Under `Text constraints -> Text/regexp` enter `^wrapper\(.*\)$` and tick `Invert condition`

Obviously you can tweak that regex to whatever you want. Invert condition means that the search will skip all instances where condition is met. Basically you write a regex to match what you don’t want to see and `Invert condition` is a `NOT` operator.

On my test text:

```
System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
System.out.println( wrapper( ex.getMessage() ) );
```

The second instance was not in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to replace

```
print($Argument$)
```

with

```
print(wrapper($Argument$))
```

and then get rid of any double wrappers by replacing

```
print(wrapper(wrapper($Argument$)))
```

with

```
print(wrapper($Argument$))
```